# Add argument to function after it's already been called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

For example, if I have the function:

```py
def to_full_name(first_name, last_name=None): # Note that 'last_name' is not required, so an error will not occur
    return '{} {}'.format(first_name, last_name)



# ...



a = to_full_name('John')
```

How can I add the second argument to the 'a' variable later down the line? ex:

```py
a.set_argument('last_name', 'Doe')
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Please show a little more context.

Comment: `a` is the string returned by the function; it doesn't have any 'memory' or link to the function that created it, or to the variables that were used.  You could just as well created with string with `a = '{} {}'.format('foo',None)`

Answer (score 1):

For this particular problem I would recommend a class.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, first_name=None, last_name=None):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def set_first_name(self, name):
        self.first_name = name

    def set_last_name(self, name):
        self.last_name = name

    def to_full_name(): 
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Then we  change it as follows

```
person = Person("John")
person.set_last_name("Doe")
print(person.to_full_name())
```

We can also change the values directly

```
person = Person()
person.last_name = "Doe"
person.first_name = "John"
print(person.to_full_name())
```